# Uploading an image and displaying it using a button

Tags: javascript, html

How can I display an image I uploaded immediately in HTML using button like a profile picture
Thank you

```
<div>
    <img id="myImg" class="img img-circle" src="#" alt="your image" 
        height=200 width=100>
</div>
    <input type='file' />
```

```
$(function () {
    $(":file").change(function () {
        if (this.files && this.files[0]) {
            var reader = new FileReader();

            reader.onload = imageIsLoaded;
            reader.readAsDataURL(this.files[0]);
        }
    });
});

function imageIsLoaded(e) {
    $('#myImg').attr('src', e.target.result);
    $('#yourImage').attr('src', e.target.result);
};
```

Answer (score 0):

So you essentially want an image preview without a page reload? Here is some code that will do just that.

HTML:

```
<img id="myImg" alt="your image" class="img img-circle" style="visibility: hidden; display: none" height="200" width="100">
&nbsp;
<input type="file" onchange="showimagepreview(this)" accept=".png,.jpg,.jpeg,.gif" />
```

JavaScript:

```
function showimagepreview(input) {  
    if (input.files && input.files[0]) {  
        var reader = new FileReader();  
        reader.onload = function (e) {  
            document.getElementById("myImg").setAttribute("src", e.target.result);
            document.getElementById("myImg").style = "visibility: visible; display: inline";
        }  
        reader.readAsDataURL(input.files[0]);  
    }  
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code already successfully displays the image preview. As far as I understand your question you intend to display the full image on button click.

You will need an image for that

```
<img id="yourImage">
```

on file upload you will need to store the src somewhere, for the sake of simplicity that will be a global variable here:

```
var src = "";
```

and then:

```
function imageIsLoaded(e) {
    $('#myImg').attr('src', e.target.result);
    src = e.target.result;
};
```

and the button click:

```
$("#yourbutton").click(function() {
    $("#yourImage").att("src", src);
});
```

Answer (score -1):

So basically you want to use an image as a button.Here is the solution you are looking for

```
<button>
<img src="http://www.w3.org/html/logo/downloads/HTML5_Logo_32.png" id="dagger" />
</button>

$(function(){
    $("#dagger").click(function(){
        alert("click");
    }); 
});
```